# Extra call in argument even thought documentation says it's correct

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm trying to make the following request using Alamofire in Swift 4. However, I keep getting an error saying `Extra argument in call`. This is a little funny to me because I have very similar requests elsewhere in my program and no errors are thrown.

```
Alamofire.request(Constants.URL + "objects/\(id)/\(self.info)", method: .post) {

}
```

Even funnier is that I copied a request exactly as is from the Alamofire documentation, and I still get the exact same error!

```
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/post", method: .post) {

}
```

I'm checked my version of Alamofire in my cocopods, and it is indeed Alamofire 4.7.0, which is the most recent version. I also tried restarting Xcode but to no avail. Is there something wrong that I'm doing, or is something weird going on?

Here are my imports

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import Locksmith
import SwiftyJSON
```

Comment: What is your all import statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its Alamofire bug. i found the answer. try this

```
let headers = ["Content-Type":"Application/json"]

        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
            print("Request  \(response.request!)")
            print("RESPONSE \(response.result.value!)")
            print("RESPONSE \(response.result)")
            print("RESPONSE \(response)")
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                let json = JSON(response.result.value as Any)
                print("Json is =====\(json)")

                break

            case .failure(let error):
                break


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: do u passing any parameters or headers?

Comment: No, parameters are nil. Even with parameters, however, the same error still persists.

Comment: Alamofire.upload(data, to: urlString).response { response in // method defaults to `.post`
    debugPrint(response)
}

Comment: thats should be work because its worked for me. i also got that error.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I forgot to write .responseJSON at the end of the function declaration. It's suppose to be:

```
Alamofire.request(URL, method: .post).responseJSON { response in

}
```

Nevertheless, it's still a little weird that copying directly from documentation still yields an error.